# 2004 97cc Jonny pagsta mini chopper

Tags: motorcycle

[image]
 Ok. My motorcycle wouldn't start today so I changed all the fluids and cleaned out the carb and jets set the air flow and idle screws back to what they were set to and the bike started and actually ran better then before. But I turned it off and about 30 minutes later I tried to start the bike and it made this loud POP sound and died. Went to start the bike again and it would not start. Waited about 10 min and inspected the carb and the hoses nothing looks broken. So I tried to start the bike and now it will start but as soon as you give it gas it bogges and dies. And if you don't give it any gas after about 15 sec it dies. And when the bike is running there is no funny sounds or smells.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! W